# Some HEVC videos must be decoded with LAV

Tags: ffmpeg

I tried to encode a series of png files into a HEVC codec video with ffmpeg (version modern enough) in these parameters:

ffmpeg -hwaccel cuda -r 60000/1001 -f image2 -i output%05d.png **-c:v hevc_nvenc -preset slow -profile:v main10 -level 6.2 -pix_fmt yuv444p16le** output.mkv

Then I got a mkv video file and I found that it cannot be decoded with DXV2 but with LAV Decoder, which takes up really lot of my CPU. However, I also found that the other HEVC codec video file, which has similar property of my video, can be decoded with DXV2 Decoder using my GPU. Could anyone help me find a way that, make a HEVC codec video can be decoded using GPU? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess your issue is with `-pix_fmt yuv444p16le`. I don't know what format your PNG is, but it's typically 8-bits/component RGB. You're upsampling it to 16-bits/component 4:4:4 YUV and then using that as input to the HEVC encoder at whatever is its closest-supported neighbour (10-bits/component YUV-4:4:4, according to comments in the source code).

4:4:4 is sometimes not supported by hardware decoders (see [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/yuv444-decoding-support-on-h264-avc-and-vp9/109443)). Also see this quote from [here](https://virtuallyvisual.wordpress.com/2016/02/18/microsoft-rdp-end-client-h-264-444-hardware-decode-support-on-existing-decoders-420-elegant-and-cool/):

> Many existing end-client devices/GPUs/SoC support hardware decode 4:2:0 but not 4:4:4 and whilst newer hardware and GPUs are introducing 4:4:4 decoders many existing devices only support 4:2:0 decode.

I would try `-pix_fmt p010le`, which should result in YUV-4:2:0 10-bits/component, which should work fine with all hardware decoders.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try to encode with p010le today

Comment: Really thanks! It works